# Spin up elasticsearch container locally on linux

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch, terminal

I have been reading about running elasticsearch while following this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) but when I reach on the step of running this command :

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -p 127.0.0.1:9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
```

Nothing happens, it just finsihes and nothing happens what could be wrong ?

The first command works well :

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
```

But spinning doesn't work

Comment: When I try to reproduce it and run the 2 commands, the container starts as it should.

Comment: When you do `docker run ...`, does it stop without showing any messages ?

Comment: I actually got a solution posted the answer, I was using a wrong image for my OS. But thanks a lot @Philippe and Hans

Answer (score 0):

Reason as to why it was not working it's because I was using a wrong version for my OS.

I had get a suitable version for my OS here :
[Link](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix)

Comment: But according to the link, 7.17.0 should work for all OS, right ?

Comment: Yeah, am wondering why it ddint work on 0S, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I think it's more then that. versions 7.17.0-8.1.0 not working for me too, ubuntu 20.04 and jdk 17. when I run docker run command, nothing happens.